# Harvey Hurricane Disaster Area Data Sets

Tags: data-request, us-census, geohazard

Looking for following Datasets for an ArcGIS Project

1. Damage Area affected by Hurricane Harvey
2. Recover centers per damaged areas for Harvey Hurricane
3. Population data before Harvey for affected areas
4. Population data after Harvey for effected area
5. Business Impacted in the disaster areas.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.napsgfoundation.org/hurricane-harvey-resources/ links to sources that contain some of the information you want.

Such as a link to https://respond-harvey-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/, which has base population data. As you’ll see even from this one example, what is considered an impacted area varies.